# Lebesgue point - an example

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, sobolev-spaces, bmo-martingales

How can I prove that for the function $f:\mathbb{R}^n\to \mathbb{R}$:

$$f(x) = \sin(\log |\log |x||)$$

0 is not a Lebesgue point?

The point $y$ is a **Lebesgue point** if:

$$ \lim_{r\to 0} \frac{1}{|B_r(y)|}\int_{B_r(y)} |f(x)-f(y)|\, dy =0 $$

---

In the average integral of the $f$ derivative I tried some approximation but was unsuccessful.

Comment: Pretty sure the balls in your definition of Lebesgue point need to be centered at $x$, not at the dummy variable of the integral.

Comment: $f$ is not even defined at $x=0$

Comment: In fact, $f(x)$ is not defined for any $|x| \leq 1$, so there is no hope of getting close to $x = 0$.  (Maybe one could have considered deleted balls omitting just one point (since it has measure zero).  But those nested logarithms exclude too much from the domain.)  Of course at points where $f$ is defined, the integrand in your Lebesgue point integral is bounded by $2$...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Indeed, the function is not defined at $x=0$ or on the unit sphere. But at all other points, the function is defined. But we can definitely define it at $x=0$. Let's show that no matter what value $a$  we assign to  $f$ at $x=0$, the expressions

$$ A_r =  \frac{1}{r^n}\int_{B_r (0)} |f(y) - a| dy$$

do not converge to $0$ as $r\to 0+$. WLOG we will assume $r < 1/2$.  By radial symmetry, $A_r$ is equal, up to a multiplicative constant, to

$$ r^{-n} \int_0^r |\sin (\ln |\ln s|)-a| s^{n-1} ds.$$

Change variables $s \to u = |\ln s|$ gives $du = -\frac{1}{s} ds$, and so

$$(*)\quad r^{-n} \int_{|\ln r|}^\infty |\sin (\ln u)-a| e^{-n u} du$$

Using the priodicity of $\sin$, there exists a sequence of disjoint intervals $I_k = [\alpha,\beta] + 2\pi k~,k=1,2,\dots$ such that  $|\sin (x) -a|>c_0>0$ for all $x$ in the union of the intervals (if $a=0$ choose $c_0=\frac 12$ and if $a\ne 0$ choose $c_0= |a|/2$). Now $x \in I_k$ if and only if $\ln (\alpha +2\pi k) \le  \ln x \le \ln (\beta + \pi k)$. Therefore the integral is bounded below by the sum

$$ (**) \quad c_0  \sum_{k=k(r)}^\infty  (\beta+ 2\pi k)^{-n} (\ln ( \beta +2\pi k) - \ln (\alpha +2\pi k)),$$

and where $k(r)$ is the smallest $k$ such that satisfying $\alpha + 2\pi k \ge |\ln r|$. That is

$$k(r) \sim |\ln r|/2\pi.$$

Below, $c,c',c''$ are constants not depending on $r$.

By a simple comparison argument, the general term of the series in $(**)$ is bounded below by $c k^{-n-1}$ for all $k\ge k(r)$,  and therefore the summation is bounded below by  $c' k(r)^{-n}=c''|\ln r|^{-n}$. Now $|\ln r|r \to 0$ as $r\to0$, and therefore, $\liminf_{r\to 0+} A_r = \infty$.

Comment: I am very grateful for your answer @Fnacool. One point that was not clear to me is why the exponent in $(\ast)$, that is $e^{-nu}$, is positive (I think it's because r <1/2) and how the integral $\int_\infty^{|ln r|}$ changed to $\int^\infty_{|ln r|}$.

Comment: Remeber: $s\in (0,1)$.  In particular, $|\ln s|=-\ln s$, and rherefore: 1.  $s = e^{-|\ln s|}$; 2. $d |\ln s| = d (-\ln s) = -\frac{1}{s}ds$.  (last one requires editing the answer, but the integral is correct: it is positive).